# Why does VS Code not auto-import packages using Go?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Hi I am new to Go and currently use VS Code as IDE.

I am totally new to back-end development and I am trying to use Go for the job.

While I was teaching myself via Youtube, I faced a problem.

The problem is that the VS Code does not auto-import any package made by me.

I don't know why but I did get some clues about it.

My Guess

- My editor does not recognize the location of the package

also my projects are located at C:\Users\John\Desktop\GoProjects
while the gopath=C:\Users\John\go
and the goroot=c:\go

Can anyone give me a solution to this?

[image: main.go]
[image: myapp/app.go]

Comment: Do you have go extension installed in vscode and necessary go packages that extension requires?

Comment: Yes, I think I do! But I'm not sure it the extension is the reason that's causing the problem

Comment: well extensions soes all the magic in vscode. You have install extension explicitly for every language you want  to support.

Comment: Hmm.. Well I got all the extensions installed but still nothing seems to help...

Answer (score 10):

In my case disabling `gopls` worked and easily solved the issue.

`File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Use Language Server (Type in search box and uncheck it)`

Read the complete thread here for detailed information : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2473

You can also import missing libraries using Command Palette (Cntrl + Shift + P) which is also very simple.

Open the **Command Palette** and run the command **Go: Add Import** to get a list of packages that can be imported to your Go file. Choose one and it will get added in the import block of your Go file.

Comment: READ THIS: Very unintuitive that DISABLING the language server is what's necessary. Ty!

Answer (score 6):

There is no issue in my GOPATH or GOROOT but auto import not working in my case & there is some squiggly alert in my code. I fix this by following these simple 3 steps.

1. CTRL + SHIFT + P then type go tool

[image]

2. Select install/Update Tools then select all checkbox

[image]

3. Click ok & download all packages. Now close & reopen vs code it will remove all squiggly lines & auto-import packages

I did the same thing. now everything works perfectly :).

Answer (score 3):

Just check Go: Autocomplete Unimported Packages in File > Preferences > Settings
It worked for me

[image]

Comment: How do you have that one?

Answer (score 1):

Updating Go Tools in VSCODE solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It's not a 100% perfect one though.

I don't know why Go is so inconvenient about this but here's my solution.

1. set GOPATH to my working directory, in this case C:/Users/John/GoProjects

This part is important because this is where the path, your editor begins your relative path

2. Create three directories; bin, pkg, src
3. Ctrl + Shift + P => goinstall Install/Update tools
4. In the main.go file, import the package manually.

[image]

I hope this could help people facing the same problem! Happy coding!

Comment: vscode does all of this automatically for me. But then i use go modules for my project. `go mod init packagename` in the project directory and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `go.mod` file for autoimporting. Just run `go mod init example.com/test-app` then `go mod tidy` and autoimporting will work fine.